# No Peer certificate available in android 4.4 - Code works in Android 6

Tags: android, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am struggling with an issue of calling a POST URL to get oAuth token. I am using HTTPClient to an URL to post request to get oauth access token. It works fine in Android 6 and above. The same when tried in android 5 or lower give me No Peer certificate available exception. Below is the code, I tried lot of answers in Stackoverflow and couldnt solve my issue :(.

```
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpPost = new HttpPost(address);


    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", token));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", ""));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", ""));

    String encoding = Base64.encodeToString("".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    //httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic =");

    String auth = "" + ":" + "";
    byte[] encodedAuth = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
    httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", authHeader);


    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

    //httpPost.setParams(params);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    is = httpEntity.getContent();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append(line);
    }

    reader.close();
```

Comment: Your server may use an SSL certifcate that is not trusted on earlier Android versions.

Comment: how to know about it because of the certificate older android versions are not trusting it?.. Also is it possible to ignore the certificates in earlier versions?

Comment: I tried HTTP URL connection also, But it gives me 501 response code. :(